# How to use the expression "also echt" in conversation?

Tags: expression

> Yeah, you could just as well become the next mayor! ***Also echt***, Felix. Why not just chill out?

The literal translation would be something like "so, really ...", but I wonder if this expression follows a joking remark to change the tone of the conversation into a more serious one.

- Is it an equivalent of the English expression "in all seriousness"?
- Can you also say "Also wirklich!"?
- Do these two express your annoyance?

Comment: You could translate it as "seriously".

Comment: In einer englischen Konversation?

Answer (score 2):

Nach meinem Verständnis und Sprachgebrauch lassen sich die Ausdrücke

> Also echt, Helga...

und

> Also wirklich, Helga...

in der Tat ohne Änderung der transportierten Botschaft gegeneinander austauschen.

Die Botschaft ist beidesmal: "Ich bin mit deinem Verhalten nicht einverstanden. Ich finde dein Verhalten inakzeptabel, ärgerlich oder sonstwie missbilligenswert." Oder auch kurz: Es wird eine leichte Form der Missbilligung (oder *annoyance*) ausgedrückt; **leicht**, weil man "Also echt..." typischerweise im Falle minderschwerer Übertretungen des Verhaltenskodex sagen würde. Würde man hingegen Zeuge eines Mordes, wäre es eher überraschend, man sagte:

> Also echt, Herr Müller, das hätten Sie jetzt aber nicht tun sollen.

Um angemessene Übertragungen ins Englische zu finden, wäre allerdings vielleicht das entsprechende Englisch-Forum der bessere Ort?

Comment: Richtig. Umso mehr als "echt", eigentlich das Gegenteil von unecht,  sich erst in den letzten Jahrenzehnten als (etwas derbere) Alternative zu "wirklich" durchgesetzt hat und sich dann, allem Anschein nach, genau wie "wirklich" verhält.

Comment: "Also wirklich" wird häufig auch ironisch (mit positivem Unterton) verwendet. Für "also echt" habe ich diese Bedeutung noch nicht im Alltagsdeutsch gehört.